# Java multithreading - reader and writer thread in synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, synchronized-block

This is a question from a job interview:

How to identify read thread and write thread in a synchronized block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do something like:

```
Thread current = Thread.currentThread()
```

And now; when you have a map/list/... of threads, you can simply compare references. Simple example:

You add two fields to your class:

```
private Thread reader = 
private Thread writer =
```

And then you could do

```
synchronized foo() {
  if (Thread.currentThread() == reader) ...
```

And for the record: although things look that easy, a person dealing with "this problem" should rather step back: this smells [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) 
all over the place.

Meaning: in the "real" world; I would consider code like this to be **bad practice**. Most likely, it tries to solve a problem that should be solved in other ways!

So, the answer to an interviewer would better be a combination of the direct technical answer; but pointing out that "bad practice" issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may check if current thread is instanceOf Reader or Writer

Comment: `Thread.currentThread()` will always return something that is `instanceof Thread`.  But `extends Thread` usually is a code smell, so merely looking at the _type_ of the current Thread object won't tell you anything if your code doesn't stink.  Like GhostCat said, it's better to use the _identity_ of the object.  Best of all though would be to not write code that does different things depending on who's calling it.